# Python Selenium check for new links and put in text file if not exist

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I would like to automate the following situation:

1. determine all links on a website
2. put them into one file
3. check if there are new links on the website (compare with the previous file)
4. if there are new links on the website, then put them in the file

Any ideas on how I could implement this? How should i save the links? (as json? simple?)

What I have so far:

```
links = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("[href*='search']")
links2 = [elem.get_attribute('href') for elem in links]
print(links2)
```

Output:

```
['https://www.xyz/testing', 'https://www.xyz/testing2', 'hhttps://www.xyz/testing3']
```

Comment: If you could just use a set() and just append to that and you will get all unique values.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a Python solution that adds new links to a file called `links.txt` every time it is run. This assumes that you have `selenium` installed, and that you have `chromedriver` on your System PATH.

```py
import codecs
import json
import os
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

# Spin up a new Chrome browser
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-automation"])
options.add_experimental_option("useAutomationExtension", False)
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)

# Open the URL and then get all links from the page
driver.get("https://seleniumbase.io/demo_page")
links = driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "a[href]")
links = [elem.get_attribute('href') for elem in links]
links = list(set(links))  # Remove duplicates

# Get existing links from "links.txt", then combine all links
abs_path = os.path.abspath(".")
file_name = "links.txt"
file_path = os.path.join(abs_path, file_name)
file_links = []
if os.path.exists(file_path):
    with open(file_path, "r") as f:
        json_file_links = f.read().strip()
        file_links = json.loads(json_file_links)
all_links = list(set(links + file_links))

# Print each link on a new line
for link in all_links:
    print(link)

# Save all links in json format into "links.txt"
json_all_links = json.dumps(all_links)
links_file = codecs.open(file_path, "w+", encoding="utf-8")
links_file.writelines(json_all_links)
links_file.close()

driver.quit()  # Close the browser
```

Here's the printed output of that for the URL provided. (The links will also be in a file called `links.txt`.)

```
https://github.com/seleniumbase/SeleniumBase
https://seleniumbase.com/
https://seleniumbase.io/
https://seleniumbase.io/demo_page/
```

Comment: Thanks, thats helping a lot. Now it works!

Comment: That's great to hear!